# Revolving/dropping in text with jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am trying to mimic the functionality that exists in the header text that appears on [Gumroad's homepage](http://gumroad.com), which has components of the line of text that revolve/drop in and out. The text that remains constant dynamically shifts horizontally as new text is dropped in.

I found an answer on stackoverflow that answers a similar question [see that answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044753/jquery-ui-flipping-text-like-in-gumroad-com). But the problem is that the solution uses absolute positioning, and I need to avoid using that because I would like to use Twitter Bootstrap and need the text to be responsive.

I would like to accomplish this using Jquery if possible (as opposed to CSS3) and I have come up with something close to what I need, which you can see on my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattklangan/AkbQp/).

```
<h2>
Enjoy this rotation
<span id="dynamic-text-wrapper">
    <span id="old-text">from the comfort of your home</span>
    <span id="new-text">from the comfort of your home</span>
</span>
today!
```

**The problem with what I've come up with is that the text that remains constant shifts vertically as the new text is dropped in.**

**BONUS:** I would also like the text to the right of the text that drops in to slide left or right dynamically depending on the dimensions of the text that is dropped in, but I don't even know where to begin to figure out how to accomplish that. If someone could point me in the direction of a possible effect to use so I can read up on the documentation, I would be grateful!

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is wrap your "Enjoy this rotation" and "today!" texts in a span and apply a class like this :

```
.static-text {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Also make sure that you add `vertical-align: top;` to your `#old-text` and `#new-text` elements :

**[See updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AkbQp/2/)**

Comment: @Brewel, thank you for your recommendation. It gets me closer! This does stick the text at the top. Any idea how I could avoid it bumping text up and down that might appear in a div below? **[See updated Fiddle for an example with your suggestion added](http://jsfiddle.net/mattklangan/AkbQp/3/)**

Comment: Although I am still searching for a way to achieve this on a single line, I was able to hack together a workaround for those who might be interested in a potential solution. Here's the **[updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattklangan/AkbQp/5/)**.